# JQuery confilct

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have a weird situation where two JQueries having conflict.

Here are the codes:

First Code:

This code used to generate a tree list on the left of the page and modify some parts of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#generate").click(function() {
            var texts = [];
            $("form label").each(function() {
                var oLabel = $(this);
                var oInput = oLabel.next();
                if(oLabel.val() == "Best Regards,")
                {
                    alert(oInput.val());
                    texts.push(oLabel.text());
                    texts.push(oInput.val());
                }
                else
                    texts.push(oLabel.text() + " " + oInput.val());
            });
                texts[0] += " " + texts[1];
                texts[1] = texts[2] + " " + texts[3];
                for(i=4;i<texts.length;i++)
                    texts[i-2] = texts[i];
                texts[texts.length-2] = texts[texts.length-3];
                texts[texts.length-3] = $("#agent").val() ;
                texts[texts.length-1] = null;
            $("#cont").fadeOut('fast').hide();
            $("#fe_text").html(texts.join("\n"));
            $("#template").css('visibility','visible');
            $("#template").fadeIn('slow').show();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Second Code:

This code is used to copy specific `<textarea>` to clipboard

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swf/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var clip = null;
    try
    {
    function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }
    function init() {
        clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        clip.setHandCursor( true );

        clip.addEventListener('load', function (client) {
            debugstr("Flash movie loaded and ready.");
        });

        clip.addEventListener('mouseOver', function (client) {
            // update the text on mouse over
            clip.setText( $('fe_text').value );
        });

        clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
            debugstr("Copied text to clipboard: " + text );
        });

        clip.glue( 'd_clip_button', 'd_clip_container' );
    }

    function debugstr(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = msg;
        $('d_debug').appendChild(p);
    }
</script>
```

and here is the error (using Google Chrome JS Console).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'treeview' of null
  (anonymous function)template2.php:17
  c.extend.readyjquery-1.4.min.js:314
  Mjquery-1.4.min.js:483
template2.php:91Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hide' of null
  (anonymous function)template2.php:91
  onload
```

I hope anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

You're replacing jQuery's `$` function.
Don't do that.  Instead, use jQuery.

Comment: In which part? I got those two code online, and both are working fine separately but when combined, I get the mentioned error :(

Comment: not thoroughly, I'm a beginner in AJAX and JQuery, my main programming languages are PHP and C#. So I've searched online for codes to help me do what I need. The copy to clipboard is found on Google.

Comment: I need to have this code running cause I have deadline that I'm about to pass :( I'm doing this for my work, and need to have it running in around 2 days. I've already finished everything except the errors I'm having. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Patches: No errors found on it!! But when I remove it, everything works fine except the copy :(

Comment: Change `$('d_debug').appendChild` to `$('#d_debug').append(...)`

Comment: @SLaks: Removed it, as this is only for debugging which is working when the script is working only!!

Comment: and still having the same problem.

Comment: you got another one: clip.setText( $('fe_text').value );

Comment: @sikas note that in jquery, when selecting an id you have to have a '#' ahead of it. When selecting a css class, you have to have '.' ahead of it.